# Composite Primary Key or Foreign Key

Tags: t-sql, database-design

I have a data model which is as follows ...

- A Topic can have multiple Exercises (ExerciseTopic(FK) references TopicId(PK))
- An Exercise can have multiple Questions (Exercise(FK) references ExerciseId(PK))
- A Question can have multiple (4) AnswerChoices

[image]

I would like to have a three part primary key for AnswerChoices table as it is this combination that will uniquely identify each choice.

- Will I need a foreign key in AnswerChoices table for data integrity purposes or
- Will the composite primary key be sufficient? If the foreign key is required, will it be two part composite foreign key (ExerciseId, QuestionId)?

Sample data ...

- Topic (T1)

  - Exercise E1

    - Question 1 (AnswerChoices: a, b, c, d)
    - Question 2 (AnswerChoices: a, b, c, d)
    - Question 3 (AnswerChoices: a, b, c, d)
  - Exercise E2

    - Question 1 (AnswerChoices: a, b, c, d)
    - Question 2 (AnswerChoices: a, b, c, d)
    - Question 3 (AnswerChoices: a, b, c, d)
  - Exercise E3

    - Question 1 (AnswerChoices: a, b, c, d)
    - Question 2 (AnswerChoices: a, b, c, d)
    - Question 3 (AnswerChoices: a, b, c, d)
- Topic (T2)

  - Exercise E1

    - Question 1 (AnswerChoices: a, b, c, d)
    - Question 2 (AnswerChoices: a, b, c, d)
    - Question 3 (AnswerChoices: a, b, c, d)
  - Exercise E2

    - Question 1 (AnswerChoices: a, b, c, d)
    - Question 2 (AnswerChoices: a, b, c, d)
    - Question 3 (AnswerChoices: a, b, c, d)
  - Exercise E3

    - Question 1 (AnswerChoices: a, b, c, d)
    - Question 2 (AnswerChoices: a, b, c, d)
    - Question 3 (AnswerChoices: a, b, c, d)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *looks* like you'll need a four-column key in AnswerChoices: {TopicID, ExerciseID, QuestionID, ChoiceID}. And the table "AnswerChoices" should have a `foreign key (TopicID, ExerciseID, QuestionID) references Questions (TopicID, ExerciseID, QuestionID)`.

Answer (score 0):

Does not need to be an "or"
Can have composite and foreign
One option

```
Exercise:
PK TopicID FK to Topic
PK ExerciseID

Question:
PK TopicID FK to Exercise
PK ExerciseID FK to Exercise
PK QuestionID

AnswerChoices:
PK TopicID FK to Question
PK ExerciseID FK to Question
PK QuestionID FK to Question
PK ChoiceID

UserAnsers:
PK UserID FK to Users
PK TopicID FK to AnswerChoices
PK ExerciseID FK to AnswerChoices
PK QuestionID FK to AnswerChoices
PK ChoiceID FK to AnswerChoices
```

If the user can only select one answer then take PK off ChoiceID